# Computing the signature of a triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In linear algebra, how to compute the signature of a matrix, when the matrix is triangular.

In particular, what it would be for the matrix

$\begin{pmatrix} -1&1&-3 \\1&-1&0 \\ -3&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$